# Gnome Extension not installing

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell-extension

I just did a fresh install of ubuntu and I installed the gnome shell like the website told me to and when I click on the switch toggle, it slides to On but nothing else happens, no prompt to install, nothing.

When I open the dev console I see this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) GDBus.Error:org.gnome.Shell.DownloadInfoError: 6

I have no idea what's wrong and why it's not even prompting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, ca-certificates was not installed, installed it and rebooted and success it's working now. if anyone else runs into this, I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 3):

**WORKAROUND**

I had this exact error as well, i ended up installing manually the extension (which merely consists of dragging stuff and renaming once) through this guide:

https://www.pragmaticlinux.com/2021/06/manually-install-a-gnome-shell-extension-from-a-zip-file/

basically :

- download zip
- go to /home/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
- extract it there
- open the extracted folder
- open metadata.json
- find uuid and copy it (without the "")
- name the folder you extracted with this uuid
- <kbd>Alt+F2</kbd> then <kbd>r</kbd> to restart gnome
- checkout extensions.gnome.org
- turn the extension on

hopefully this worked for you

(don't forget to download the correct version of the extension based on your gnome version, to check gnome version : $ gnome-shell --version)

Comment: Now (at least since Ubuntu 22.04) there is a new app called `gnome-extension-app` which lists your current extensions and whether they are compatible. The `Alt-F2 + r` is important to refresh the list if you make changes. Make sure to close and reopen this app. so it shows you the current state.